# Can a native resolve function throw?

Tags: javascript, exception, promise

Lets say I'm on Chrome. I do this:

```
new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    // ... do some work
    resolve('foo');
}).then(doStuff).then(doMoreStuff);
```

Can the call to 'resolve' throw an exception? Is there anything doStuff or doMoreStuff could do, that would make 'resolve' throw an exception?

Comment: No. if you call resolve the promise is resolved and never changes it state again. So nothing that happens in doStuff or doMoreStuff can change the state from resolved to rejected

Comment: `doStuff` and `doMoreStuff` are not executed until **after** `resolve` is called. There is no time travel in javascript :p

Comment: I wasn't sure if 'resolve' just "set a flag and returned", or if it instead "set a flag and also run any work that was waiting for that flag to be set".

Answer (score 0):

If `doStuff` or `doMoreStuff` throw an exception, it will be thrown in the context of the calls to `.then()`, not the body of the function. By the time `.then()` is called, that function has returned. The code there is executed asynchronously.

If you want to catch the exception, you need to put `try` around the call to `doStuff`

```
new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    // ... do some work
    resolve('foo');
}).then(x => {
try {
    doStuff(x);
} catch (e) {
    console.log("Error in doStuff");
}).then(doMoreStuff);
```

Comment: If `dostuff` throws an error, it won't be caught in this catch. You'll end up with an unhandled rejection. For example if `let doStuff = () => {throw(new Error("Whoops"))}` What happens?

Comment: You're right, I forgot that `.then()` is executed asynchronously.